openapi generator maven plugin ignore custome template
I would to customize template of generated models to avoid getter, setter and other method. I prefer using Lombok annotation.
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api/core-v1.yml</inputSpec>
                <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                <library>spring-boot</library>
                <configOptions>
                    <serializationLibrary>jackson</serializationLibrary>
                    <x-content-type>application/json</x-content-type>
                    <annotationLibrary>swagger2</annotationLibrary>
                    <generatedConstructorWithRequiredArgs>false</generatedConstructorWithRequiredArgs>
                    <generatedConstructorWithNoArgs>false</generatedConstructorWithNoArgs>
                    <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
                    <additionalModelTypeAnnotations>@lombok.Data @lombok.NoArgsConstructor @lombok.AllArgsConstructor</additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
                    <templateDirectory>${project.basedir}\JavaSpring</templateDirectory>
                </configOptions>
                <cleanupOutput>true</cleanupOutput>
                <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                <typeMappings>
                    <!-- convert Double to BigDecimal -->
                    <typeMapping>Double=java.math.BigDecimal</typeMapping>
                </typeMappings>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

I have add my model.mustache file under the path
resources/JavaSpring

I have tried
<templateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/JavaSpring</templateDirectory>

and
<templateDirectory>${project.basedir}\src\main\resources\JavaSpring\/templateDirectory>

but I've got same result

The problem was position of configuration. I moved outside configOption and all works fine.
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api/core-v1.yml</inputSpec>
                <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                <library>spring-boot</library>
                <configOptions>
                    <serializationLibrary>jackson</serializationLibrary>
                    <x-content-type>application/json</x-content-type>
                    <annotationLibrary>swagger2</annotationLibrary>
                    <generatedConstructorWithRequiredArgs>false</generatedConstructorWithRequiredArgs>
                    <generatedConstructorWithNoArgs>false</generatedConstructorWithNoArgs>
                    <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
                    <additionalModelTypeAnnotations>@lombok.Data @lombok.NoArgsConstructor @lombok.AllArgsConstructor</additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
                </configOptions>
                <templateDirectory>${project.basedir}\JavaSpring</templateDirectory>
                <cleanupOutput>true</cleanupOutput>
                <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                <typeMappings>
                    <!-- convert Double to BigDecimal -->
                    <typeMapping>Double=java.math.BigDecimal</typeMapping>
                </typeMappings>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

